# Did Lord Vishnu incarnate as Kalki in any of the previous Yugas?

Tags: vishnu, yuga, time, kali-yuga, kalki

Lots of Vishnu avatars have repeated during the previous Chaturyugas.

Are there any references citing the Kalki avatar in previous Yugas?

Comment: "Lots of Vishnu avatars were repeated during previous Chaturyugas". Can you provide some examples?

Comment: http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/7189/3500  Comment section of this answer provides some information on repetition of avatars

Comment: @Sai Vishnu has has three Vamana incarnations in this Kalpa; see here:  http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/7210/36 And at least according to ISKCON, Vishnu has had two Matsya incarnations in this Kalpa, which is what Anil was referring to when he referenced the comment section of my answer.  (But I'm not sure that ISKCON is right about this, because they seem to be splitting a Mastya story given in a single chapter into two stories.)  And the Padma Purana describes a Rama incarnation in an earlier Kalpa or Mahakalpa.  And there have been multiple Varaha incarnations.  Whew!

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan Quite interesting (especially the Lord Vamana one)! The way I interpret a 'repitition' of an Avatar is if the same event happens again. Because incarnating as a fish twice to do different things, atleast in my opinion, would not count as the same incarnation twice. Similarly with the Vamana one, from what I have read in your question, it seems that  the events are totally different. How then can we say that the avatars were repeated! It is like saying the Rama and Krishna were the same Avatar (although they are the same Purusha) just because both were humans! All the best

Comment: @Sai Yeah, in these so-called "repetitions" there are only similarities in broad strokes, like "Vishnu incarnated as a dwarf to stop a Yagna" or "Vishnu incarnated as a fish during a greasy flood".  I think probably the Rama one is the closest example of a true repetition, the characters all have the same names, it's just that some of the events are different.  By the way, another example of a repeted incarnation is the Vadavagni fire: http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/7082/36 I didn't mention it in that answer, but the Mahabharata says that Vadavagni is an incarnation of Vishnu.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

First of all, we know for a fact that Kalki doesn't come in every Kali Yuga.  In [this chapter](https://books.google.com/books?id=nckrAAAAMAAJ&dq=%2224th%20treta%22&pg=PA138#v=onepage&q&f=false) of the Matsya Purana (an important Hindu scripture), various incarnations of Vishnu in the present Vaivasvata Manvantara are listed, but Kalki is only mentioned once, in the current Kali Yuga. [This excerpt](http://www.hinduscriptures.in/Content/Articles/PDFs/27478/62f_chapter_19_2.pdf#toolbar=0&pagemode=none&view=FitBH&page=1%22) from the Skanda Purana says the same thing.  (See my questions [here](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/7192/36), [here](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/7194/36), and [here](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/7221/36) relating to these lists.)

And we can find explicit references to how Kali Yugas have ended in the past. In particular, [this chapter](http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m07/m07067.htm) of the Drona Parva of the Mahabharata describes how Vishnu's incarnation Parashurama brought about the end of the 19th Kali Yuga of the Vaivasvata Manvantara by killing the kings of the world:

> Even the great ascetic Rama, the hero worshipped by all heroes, that son of Jamadagni, of great fame, will die, without being contented (with the period of his life). Rooting out all evils from the earth, he caused the primeval Yuga to set in. Having obtained unrivalled prosperity, no fault could be seen in him. His father having been slain and his calf having been stolen by the Kshatriyas, he without any boast, slew Kartavirya who had never been vanquished before by foes. With his bow he slew four and sixty times ten thousand Kshatriyas already within the jaws of death. In that slaughter were included fourteen thousand Brahmana-hating Kshatriyas of the Dantakura country, all of whom he slew. Of the Haihayas, he slew a thousand with his short club, a thousand with his sword, and a thousand by hanging. Heroic warriors, with their cars, steeds, and elephants, lay dead on the field, slain by the wise son of Jamadagni, enraged at the slaughter of his father. And Rama, on that occasion, slew ten thousand Kshatriyas with his axe.

But as I discuss in [this answer](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/7993/36), Vishnu did take one earlier Kalki-like incarnation in the Swayambhuva Manvantara.  His name was Pramati (as opposed to the present Kalki who will be named Vishnu Yasha), and his story is described in [this excerpt](http://gdurl.com/KrG5) from the Matsya Purana:

> King Pramati of the Bhrigu family and Chandramasa gotra was born at the end of Swayambhuva Manu in the Sandhyamsha period, to inflict proper punishment on the sinners. That king travelled all over the earth for 30 years and collected arms and ammunitions, elephants, horses and chariots and marched with a vast army consisting of horses and elephants and accompanied by 100,000 Brahmana soldiers armed with various kinds of weapons, against the Mlecchas and destroyed them. After killing all the Sudra kings he annihilated all the hypocrites After destroying all the sinners and subduing the people living in the North, central regions, the mountaineers, the inhabitants in the East and West, the residents on the Vindhyas, the Deccanis, the Dravidians, the Singhalese, the inhabitants of the Mleccha countnes...
>
> King Pramati was born of Vishnu's part in Manu's family and was famous as Chandramasa. He roamed about the Earth for 20 years and killed all the wicked men in his 32nd year.

Comment: Thanks keshav! i read all those questions and answers already except the last one.  Yes, the story of king Pramati looks similar to story of Kalki. I read from kalki Purana that Swayambhuva Manu got boon from Vishnu and born as Dasharatha,Vasudeva and will be born as Vishnuyasa. My doubt is will manu be alive after his(ruling) manvantara?

Comment: @AnilKumar By the way, I didn't come up with the comparison of Pramati and Kalki on my own; I got it from the Skanda Purana chapter I linked.  As far as Manus go, I think they die at the end of their Manvantara.  But I don't think Krishna's father Vasudeva was a rebirth of Swayambhuva Manu.  As I discuss in this question, Vasudeva and Devaki were rebirths of Sutapas and his wife Prishni: http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/2625/36

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan - the Mahabharata reference you provide where Rishi Parashuram ushered in the Krita Yuga does not make a reference to Kali Yuga anywhere. Can you show where exactly ? All it says he brought in the Krita yuga by killing all evil. But that does not mean Kali Yuga was destroyed. Care to clarify ?

Comment: @gansub Well, the Satya Yuga only comes when the Kali Yuga, so if he brought about the beginning of the Satya Yuga then presumably he brought an end to the Kali Yuga.

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan - Not necessarily. Each avatar temporarily ushers in the Satya yuga like conditions on earth.Then normal yuga time is established. Satya yuga prevailed when Maharaja Yudhisthir was in power till Sri Krishn passed away. Then Kali set in. Similarly during during Sri Ram's reign Satya yuga was on earth till Ram disappeared and Dwapar set in.

Comment: @gansub I don't think any scriptures use the word Satya Yuga to refer to either Rama's rule or Yudhishthira's rule.

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan - really ? So Rama's rule  and Yudhisthira's rule is like Kali yuga kings rule then ?

Comment: @gansub No, I just don't think that Yugas change except at pre-ordained times.  So when Rama and Yudhishthira were ruling, it was exactly the Yuga that the Yuga lengths would tell you it should be.

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan - you are right on the overall flow of time which nobody can change except Kaala. I am referring to the process of establishing Dharma on earth by a yuga avatara. Such an individual brings about social transformation based on will alone. Kali did not set in till Sri Krishn passed away. All evil had been eliminated. Job was complete.

Comment: @gansub Well, I agree that the Kali Yuga did not begin until Krishna passed away, but Krishna did not delay the start of the Kali Yuga.  Yugas begin and end at predestined times, and Krishna was just the means by which the Kali Yuga started at exactly the time it was supposed to start.

Comment: @gansub I think we're just having a disagreement about semantics.  I fully agree with you that Rama was born to show people proper Dharma.  I just don't think the term "Satya Yuga" should be used to refer to that state of affairs.  And Hindu scripture doesn't use that term either to refer to Rama's rule.

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan http://www.vedabase.com/en/sb/11/24/2. People need to be skilled in discrimination between asat and sat. That is satya yuga according to Bhagavan . At least in Ayodhya/Vrindan and Dwarka and eventually Hastinapur people were by and large aware of what sat and asat is during Sri Krishn and Sri Ram's time.

Comment: @gansub I agree that discrimination is one characteristic of the Satya Yuga, but it is not the only characteristic.  The main religious activity of the Satya Yuga was Tapasya, in Treta Yuga it was Yagnas, in Dwapara Yuga it was adoration in person, and in Kali Yuga it is recitation of names.  Now Rama's rule did not make people revert from Yagnas to Tapasya, and Yudhishthira's rule did not make people revert from adoration in person to Tapasya.  So it is simply not the case that that society reverted to the Satya Yuga.

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan - Bhagavan is on earth in person. He is the origin of time. Yugas emanate from that person alone. Unless we behold Satya yuga and Dwaraka and Ayodhya ourselves we cannot guess. I rest my case.

Comment: @gansub I agree that Sriman Narayana could change the Yuga in violation of the scheduled time if he wanted to, but he simply did not choose to do so.  I think we should base out beliefs on scripture, and like I said there are absolutely no references to Rama's rule being the Satya Yuga in Hindu scripture.