# Why is Bhagwan incarnating as Kalki in this(particular) Kaliyuga?

Tags: vishnu, avatars, kali-yuga, kalki

Many people know about The Cycle of 4 [Yugas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yuga) and DashaAvatars of Shriman Narayana ,but very few know that the Dashaavatars are not bound to the cycle of 4 Yugas. The Avatars of Bhagwan are infinite in number and he incarnates randomly, so technically Dashaavatars are distributed over the entire [Kalpa](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kalpa_(aeon)), starting from [Varaha avatar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Varaha) before the beginning of Shweta Varaha Kalpa(current Kalpa).

[This](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hindu_units_of_time) will help those who want to understand Hindu time distribution.

My question is related to the future avatar Kalki Avatar. Since there were many Kaliyugas prior to this Kaliyuga, then why didn't Bhagawan appear in previous [Manvantara](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Manvantara) Kaliyuga? Is this Kaliyuga the most polluted?

Comment: I think there was incaranation called Pramiti in previous Kali age also... also in some ages Lord Parashurama acted as Kalki...

Comment: @Tezz Proof any puranas?

Comment: @Yogi King Pramati is very similar to Kalki Avatar. See [Did Lord Vishnu incarnate as Kalki in any of the previous Yugas?](http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/8761/3500)

Comment: @TheDestroyer http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/8762/489 See the answer.

Comment: @Yogi Yes. I was saying about that.