# Is it not possible that Lord Kalki may have already taken incarnation in the past kaliyuga?

Tags: kali-yuga, kalki

Which scriptures say that Lord Kalki will take incarnation in the current (28th) kaliyuga?

Comment: I have edited the title of ur Q. Just make sure if this is what ur Q is.. Ur previous Q title was a bit unclear.--Goyllo.

Comment: @Rickross it's totally fine  :)  My English is not good as others :)

Comment: Yes there were Kalkis before - just follow Venus in Pegasus towards Dante's own time. But this one is Hayagrivananta. India had no zodiac until 1972.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No, we know for a fact that Kalki will be born in the 28th Kali Yuga of the Vaivasvata Manvantara.  Here is what [this chapter](https://books.google.com/books?id=nckrAAAAMAAJ&dq=%2224th%20treta%22&pg=PA138#v=onepage&q&f=false) of the Matsya Purana says, in the course of describing the various incarnations of Vishnu in the Vaivasvata Manvantara:

> At the close of Kaliyuga there will be the Kalki mainfestation, in the house of Vishnuyasha, and the sage, Parasharya Vyasa will be the officiating priest. This will be the tenth incarnation, and Yajnavalkya will make his appearance before this coming mainfestation. This incarnation will destroy all the wicked ones and the hypocrites; and, with a large army of the Brahmanas, He will kill Sudra Kings and drive away all hypocrisy. After killing the enemies of Brahmanas and other enemies, He will march on with His army in the 28th of the Kaliyuga, and then, after purifying the Sudras, will cross the ocean, where He will destroy the sinful mixed castes and, thus fulfilling His mission, he will educate his peoples.

It's also worth noting that, as I discuss in my answer [here](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/8762/36), Vishnu has taken Kalki-like incarnations at least once before, in one of the Kali Yugas of the Swayambhuva Manvantara.

Comment: Actually the way kalki puran said about all events, looks like old kaliyuga, hence I am not sure.

Comment: @Goyllo The Puranas often speak about future events in a past tense, that's just their style.  But the Kalki Purana is definitely talking about the present Kali Yuga.