# Which Puranas say Kalki will be born in Tamil Nadu?

Tags: vishnu, puranas, sri-vaishnava, kalki

Among the Dasavataram or ten prominent incarnations of Vishnu, the last one, Kalki, has not happened yet.  Hindu scripture provides many details about him, e.g. he'll be born in the end of the Kali Yuga, his father will be named Vishnuyasha, and he will be born in a place called Shambhala.  Now I had always assumed that Shambhala was somewhere in North India, but I just found an indication that it may be somewhere else.  Let me explain.

In the beginning of [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9qrAJwjaEGI), the Sri Vaishnava lecturer U. Ve. Ananthapadmanabhachariar Swami explains the neccesity of the Alwars taking birth in South India, due to the fact that the Dasavataram were mostly restricted to North India (translated from Tamil):

> In these ten avatarams, the really significant avatarams, that is, the ones that obtained a lot of praise: Rama avataram, Balarama avataram, Krishna avataram, before that Parashurama avataram, all of these really big avatarams, even Vamana avataram, all of these happened in North India only, South India did not have that honor.  In South India, we have not seen Vishnu taking avataram from among the Dasavataram - [except for] one avataram, Matsya avataram; we have seen that Paramatma took Matsya avataram in Tamil-born Madurai in the Kritamala river.  Similarly, **the Puranas say that the avataram that will come last also, Kalki avataram, it is in Thirunelveli that Vishnu will take it**.  This is a subject where Pandits have differences of opinion.

Now the fact that Matsya avataram happened in the Kritamala river (which flows through Madurai) is described in [this chapter](https://www.vedabase.com/en/sb/8/24) of the Srimad Bhagavatam. But I'm interested in the part in bold.  My question is, where do the Puranas say that Kalki will be born in Thirunelveli, a place near the Southern coast of Tamil Nadu?

On a side note, it's possible that Shambhala is in North India, but as a result of Kalpa Bheda Kalki could sometimes be born in Thirunelveli instead of Shambhala.

Comment: What is Sanskrit name of Thirunelveli ?

Comment: @TheDestroyer I'm not sure about that.  By the way, Ananthapadmanabhariar Swami doesn't even use the name Thirunelveli in the video, he uses the older Tamil name Thenpandi Cheemai.

Comment: @TheDestroyer THIRU = ( Thiru is tamil word means highest, pure), Nel  = Paddy, Veli =hedge or fence .... from that it came..

Comment: I also heard from parents that Kalki will be born in Tamil nadu - what about Lakshmi? where she will descend if Kalki in TN?

Comment: @AkshayS I think the Kalki Purana says Kalki's wife will be from Sri Lanka.  So he may just travel a short distance to get married.

Comment: @AkshayS Many Puranas say Kalki will born in Shambala. But some people say Shambala is located in Southern tamilnadu not in Himalayas. But if we know exact Sanskrit name of Tirunelveli, we can search easily in Puranas. Goddess Lakshmi as Ramaa will be born on Simhala Dvipa which has 7 islands i think. So, it can be Sri Lanka or UK or even Mumbai (city of seven islands)

Comment: @TheDestroyer Oh, you've also heard people say Shambhala is in Tamil Nadu?

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan Yes. Some say it is in Himalayas but some say it is in Tamilnadu. Read long ago on some blog.

Comment: @TheDestroyer Do we know where did previous Kalki avatar was born?

Comment: @AkshayS https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/8761/3500

Comment: Based on the goal of Kalki avatara, and the mindset of people in TamilNadu, I would agree that he should be born in TN.

Comment: @ram that is not a nice thing to say.. some politicians and fringe elements in TamilNadu have atheistic and crude view against some philosophies of Hinduism, that doesn't mean the whole tamilnadu mindset is bad. Tamilnadu still has the most number of Hindu temples in India. People have always been greatly religious and spiritual.

Comment: @subject-q - i know, i am from TN. kalki avatar has to take out the worst offenders - many of which are in TN